# Can't connect to LDAP server

Tags: ldap

I followed **[installing ldap on centos](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-ldap-389-directory-server-on-a-centos-6-vps/)** guide to setup LDAP server on my server,after completing all the steps of installation i executed `ldapsearch -x -b "dc=test,dc=com" -d1` this command to test my installation but it gave me following error:

```
ldap_create                                                                  
ldap_sasl_bind                                                               
ldap_send_initial_request                                                    
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0                                                    
ldap_int_open_connection                                                     
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP localhost:389                                      
ldap_new_socket: 3                                                      
ldap_prepare_socket: 3                                             
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying ::1 389                                      
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 3 tm: -1 async: 0                                  
attempting to connect:                                                    
connect errno: 111                                            
ldap_close_socket: 3                                     
ldap_new_socket: 3                             
ldap_prepare_socket: 3                                   
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 127.0.0.1:389                           
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 3 tm: -1 async: 0                              
attempting to connect:                                     
connect errno: 111                                   
ldap_close_socket: 3                          
ldap_err2string                                            
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

Is this the issue of my LDAP installation or some certificate authority issue?
I am trying this on Centos6 for LDAP version3.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Have you considered looking up errno 111?

Comment: errno 111 is connection refused error i don't think errno 111 is connected to my issue. i think it is not able to verify TLS certificate i added TLS_REQCERT never in ldap.conf file but still i m facing the same issue.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. The TLS certificate isn't relevant until after you have a connection. 'Connection refused' *is* the problem here.

Comment: ok.then could you please tell me what to look for to resolve the issue.

Comment: The usual causes of connection refusal: wrong IP, wrong port, server not running, firewall in the way.

Answer (score 5):

Check if port **389** is open on your firewall.
Use command **netstat -lt** to list the open ports.